# AWS CDK S3 BucketDeployment - fail: Inaccessible host: cdk-hnb659fds-assets-xxxxx-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I'm trying to upload static build react app to S3 to serve from cloudfront distribution but getting below error message. I have bootstrapped with correct AWS account and region.

*fail: Inaccessible host: cdk-hnb659fds-assets-xxxxx-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be available in the us-east-1' region.*

**Sample code**

```
new s3Deploy.BucketDeployment(this, 'WebAppDeploy', {
      prune: true,
      sources: [
        s3Deploy.Source.asset(path.join(__dirname, `../../../client/bulid`)),
      ],
      destinationBucket: props.hostingBucket,
    });
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that the S3 bucket is not accessible. Check the permissions of the bucket.

Comment: @AlessandroBaffa, Above hosting bucket is created as part of CDK deploy and once created trying to upload content via CDK. I presume permission should be part of CDK deploy? Thanks!

Comment: @AlessandroBaffa, Above S3 bucket is accessible to upload other asset zip folders as part to CDK deploy, I'm getting this error message when trying to upload content to other S3 bucket as part of stack instructions.

Comment: FTR: I believe this is related to https://github.com/davidtucker/ps-serverless-app/issues/2